# ADODB affected rows return trigger's affected rows

Tags: sql-server, vba, ado, adodb

I have a VBA that runs a command text to update a table. The table has a trigger on UPDATE.
When I do:

```
Set rs = cmd1.Execute(affectedCount)
```

the affectedCount returns affected rows from trigger (I think).

How do I make it return the original update statement's affected row count?

Comment: Which database - MySQL, SQL Server? If you add the appropriate tag, it is likely that you will get more answers.

Comment: Would be helpful to see more of the code.  Does it use inline SQL, or call a stored procedure?

Comment: It uses Access 2k3 front and SQL Server 2000 backend.

Comment: The way it uses the command is by CommandText in VBA and have UPDATE statement written in the code. Then that command is executed as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, I had a similar problem a while ago. I'm not sure if it's related but ADODB would get "confused" by the "# records affected" messages that were generated by SQL Server.

We solved this by adding

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

To the top of affected triggers / procedures to suppress the message. You can then try running your statement from SQL Management Studio to see exactly which "# records affected" messages are being generated.

Don't know if this will help but maybe worth a try.